# mysql subquery load data in file from large files

Tags: mysql

mytext.txt

```
`name`
sreekanth
`age`
18 
`grade`
b a
c c
d d
```

we need to insert the data into 2 tables my table structure is

```
table1                   table2
id content                ids id content_description
```

can you please suggest me the query 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`'

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further which values you want to insert into which columns? There seems to be data for columns `name, age` and `grade` but your tables have different columns.

Comment: `LOAD DATA` can only load into a single table at a time. Furthermore, the format of the input file is `<data for column 1>,<data for column 2>`, etc, not `<label>\n<data>\n<label>\n<data>`, etc. Though `LOAD DATA` allows one to specify an import format somewhat, including the order and separation characters of of the data, the format which you seem to be using is not something that you can specify in MySQL.